# Python - probability of a random number between 0 and 1

Tags: python, probability

I know that we use random.random() to generate a random decimal between 0 and 1.
Is the probability that the random number is less than .5 equal to 50%? 
And that the random number is greater than .5 equal to 50%?

Comment: It should be, but why don't you run a billion random numbers and count them up just to be sure?

Comment: You can read about the system used by `random.random()` at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is what `random.random()` is trying to do. However, if you require a cryptographically-secure random number, use something like `random.SystemRandom()`.

Comment: @Sam does that article address the transition from a bit pattern to a floating point number? This seems like a valid question.

Comment: "greater than 0.5" and "less than 0.5" can't both be exactly 50% likely, because then `random()` would never return 0.5 ;-)

Comment: @Kevin easily fixed by specifying `>= 0.5` instead of `> 0.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From docs:

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(), which generates a random float **uniformly** in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0). Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator.

Comment: This answer depends on you knowing the precise definition of "uniformly". For example, will it ever generate a denormalized number?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick test using the following:

```
import random

random.seed( None )

less_than_half = 0
greater_than_half = 0
equal_to_half = 0

for i in range( 0, 2**26 ):
    x = random.random()
    if x < .5:
        less_than_half += 1
    elif x > .5:
        greater_than_half += 1
    else:
        equal_to_half += 1

print less_than_half
print greater_than_half
print equal_to_half
```

Running four times (due to memory errors), I had a total of 134,217,147 results less than .5, 134,218,309 results greater than .5, and none equal to .5.
That resulted a total of 49.9997836% of the results being less than .5.

Actual results may vary due to a seed of your system clock.

Comment: I bet your memory errors go away if you use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: @Robᵩ Didn't know about xrange, but yes, it solved the issue (up to 2^30 due to long limitations). Thanks!

Comment: The odds of hitting a floating point value exactly are about 1 in 2**52, so it's not surprising that none were equal to 0.5.

Comment: FFH, consider flipping to Python3 as your default, and you don't have to remember dumb hacks like "xrange" and other ugly warts. But you will have to put parens around your print args.

Answer (score 0):

A small snippet for testing it yourself. But what Chad Miller said seems the most correct answer. It will indeed always have a slightly lower probability of generating a number greater than 0.5, than the probability of generating a number lesser than 0.5.
This is due to the fact that (0.5,1.0) is a **smaller infinite set of numbers** than [0.0,0.5), because the 0.0 is included and the 1.0 is excluded.

```
import random

N_ITER = 10000000
results_greater = 0
results_lesser = 0
for i in xrange(N_ITER):
    random_number = random.random()
    results_greater += random_number > 0.5
    results_lesser += random_number < 0.5
print results_greater / float(N_ITER)
print results_lesser / float(N_ITER)
```

Comment: The difference in the odds is approximately 1/2**52. I challenge you to measure it.